# Connecting Wordpress gallery to custom categories (taxonomy)

Tags: categories, taxonomy, gallery

I want to use the Wordpress gallery to show all pictures of one category in a gallery (on a fixed page), which I do not have to update all the time by inserting the pictures manually.

So I added the category feature into media with this function:

```
function is_add_categories_to_attachments() {
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'is_add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

Great, that worked. In the media menu I can add as many categories I want to now. In my case I made three of them, named alpha, beta and gamma.

Then I wanted to post a gallery on a fixed page with one category:

```
[gallery type="squares" category="alpha" order="DESC" orderby="ID" link="file"]
```

But that did not work and I had to use the post_gallery filter in my child's functions.php, so that I can change the code there, but I have absolutely NO CLUE how to enter the category recognisation into that gallery_shortcut:

```
function is_gallery($output, $attr) {
$post = get_post();

static $instance = 0;
$instance++;

if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
    // 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
    if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) )
        $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
    $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
}

// Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
if ( $output != '' )
    return $output;

// We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
    $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
    if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
        unset( $attr['orderby'] );
}

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
    'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
    'itemtag'    => 'dl',
    'icontag'    => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns'    => 3,
    'size'       => 'thumbnail',
    'include'    => '',
    'exclude'    => '',
    'link'       => ''
), $attr, 'gallery'));

$id = intval($id);
if ( 'RAND' == $order )
    $orderby = 'none';

if ( !empty($include) ) {
    $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

    $attachments = array();
    foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
        $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
    }
} elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
}

if ( empty($attachments) )
    return '';

if ( is_feed() ) {
    $output = "\n";
    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
    return $output;
}

$itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
$captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
$icontag = tag_escape($icontag);
$valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) )
    $itemtag = 'dl';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) )
    $captiontag = 'dd';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) )
    $icontag = 'dt';

$columns = intval($columns);
$itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
$float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

$selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

$gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
    $gallery_style = "
    <style type='text/css'>
        #{$selector} {
            margin: auto;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-item {
            float: {$float};
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: {$itemwidth}%;
        }
        #{$selector} img {
            border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
    </style>";
$size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

$i = 0;
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    if ( ! empty( $link ) && 'file' === $link )
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, false, false );
    elseif ( ! empty( $link ) && 'none' === $link )
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false );
    else
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, true, false );

    $image_meta  = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

    $orientation = '';
    if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) )
        $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
    $output .= "
        <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
            $image_output
        </{$icontag}>";
    if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
        $output .= "
            <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
            " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
            </{$captiontag}>";
    }
    $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
    if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
        $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
}

$output .= "
        <br style='clear: both;' />
    </div>\n";

return $output;
}
add_filter("post_gallery", "is_gallery",10,2);
```

Can you show me how to insert the category feature into the galley_shortcode?

Thank you in advance.

---

Would that be correct then?

```
function is_gallery($output, $attr) {
$post = get_post();

static $instance = 0;
$instance++;

if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
// 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) )
    $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
$attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
}

// Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
if ( $output != '' )
return $output;

// We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid     orderby statement
if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
$attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
    unset( $attr['orderby'] );
}

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'order'      => 'ASC',
'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
'itemtag'    => 'dl',
'icontag'    => 'dt',
'captiontag' => 'dd',
'columns'    => 3,
'size'       => 'thumbnail',
'include'    => '',
'exclude'    => '',
'link'       => ''
), $attr, 'gallery'));

$id = intval($id);
if ( 'RAND' == $order )
$orderby = 'none';

$beta_attachments = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'posts_per_page' => 0,
'category_name' => 'beta', // note: use category SLUG
) );

$beta_id_array = array();
foreach ( $beta_attachments as $beta ) {
$beta_id_array[] = $beta->ID;
}
$beta_ids = implode( ',', $beta_id_array );

$gamma_attachments = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'posts_per_page' => 0,
'category_name' => 'gamma', // note: use category SLUG
) );

$gamma_id_array = array();
foreach ( $gamma_attachments as $gamma ) {
$gamma_id_array[] = $gamma->ID;
}
$gamma_ids = implode( ',', $gamma_id_array );

$alpha_attachments = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'posts_per_page' => 0,
'category_name' => 'alpha', // note: use category SLUG
) );

$alpha_id_array = array();
foreach ( $alpha_attachments as $alpha ) {
$alpha_id_array[] = $alpha->ID;
}
$alpha_ids = implode( ',', $alpha_id_array );

if ( !empty($include) ) {
$_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

$attachments = array();
foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
    $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
}
} elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
} else {
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
}

if ( empty($attachments) )
return '';

if ( is_feed() ) {
$output = "\n";
foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
    $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
return $output;
}

$itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
$captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
$icontag = tag_escape($icontag);
$valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) )
$itemtag = 'dl';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) )
$captiontag = 'dd';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) )
$icontag = 'dt';

$columns = intval($columns);
$itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
$float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

$selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

$gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
$gallery_style = "
<style type='text/css'>
    #{$selector} {
        margin: auto;
    }
    #{$selector} .gallery-item {
        float: {$float};
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        width: {$itemwidth}%;
    }
    #{$selector} img {
        border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
    }
    #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
</style>";
$size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

$i = 0;
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
if ( ! empty( $link ) && 'file' === $link )
    $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, false, false );
elseif ( ! empty( $link ) && 'none' === $link )
    $image_output = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false );
else
    $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, true, false );

$image_meta  = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

$orientation = '';
if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) )
    $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

$output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
$output .= "
    <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
        $image_output
    </{$icontag}>";
if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
    $output .= "
        <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
        " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
        </{$captiontag}>";
}
$output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
    $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
}

$output .= "
    <br style='clear: both;' />
</div>\n";

return $output;
}
add_filter("post_gallery", "is_gallery",10,2);
```

### Update

hi Chip,

I understood your idea/solution now and tried it (well, copied it over thanks to you). I think the logic is working, but in practise use it does not. I used the code like that and it does not "see" the categories. Therefore it just shows an empty content (below navigation, of course).

people.php:

```
 <?php
 /**
 * Template Name: People Gallery
 */

 get_header(); ?>

<?php

$people_attachments = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'posts_per_page' => 0,
'category_name' => 'people', // note: use category SLUG
) );

$people_id_array = array();

if ( $people_attachments->have_posts() ) : while ( $people_attachments->have_posts() ) : $people_attachments->the_post();

$people_id_array[] = get_the_ID();

endwhile; endif;
// Important!
wp_reset_postdata();

$people_ids = implode( ',', $people_id_array );

echo do_shortcode( '[gallery link="file" columns="5" order="DESC" orderby="ID" include="' . $people_ids . '"]' );

?>

<?php var_dump( $people_id_array ); ?>

<?php // get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Working now

Comment: Re: `Notice: Undefined property` - check carefully for syntax errors, and spelling errors. `$people_attachments` returns a valid query object, so you shouldn't be seeing that error.

Comment: I copied the complete code, as you can see. Did YOU find any syntax error? I could not.

Comment: That error is telling you that `$people_attachments` isn't a valid query object. You need to debug to find out why.

Comment: Sorry, stupid me again, I have no clue how to do that. Can you tell me how? I tried `var_dump $people_attachments`, but that does not help me and debugging is set to true, otherwise the error would not be shown in the first place.

Comment: change `while ( $alpha_attachments->have_posts )` to `while ( $alpha_attachments->have_posts() )` - there is a missing set of ()

Comment: OMFG, that was it, it is working! Thank you, Chip and Stephen, you just saved my day and I am pretty freakin' happy. :D Thank you so much, guys. May I ask you some last thing, as you are rather more profound in Wordpress structure: When I click on the file, it loads the biggest available size. Can you tell me, where is the link creation or the expression for in which size to open. I created custom sizes vor example "gallerysize" or "blogsize", but I do not know, how to use them here in this gallery. Thank you again, you are my heroes of the week. :D If you need a beer or so, give a wink! ;)

Comment: See my edited answer. The `[gallery]` shortcode [has a "size" parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode#Options).

Comment: Thanks, but no, Chip, the [gallery size="x"] feature is just for the thumbnail size display. I am talking about which the files that get opened/displayed after clicking on one of the thumbnails.

Comment: @vega you should consider marking this question as answered and opening up a new question regarding the image size as they are separate topics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

If this is your goal:

> I want to use the Wordpress gallery to show all pictures of one category in a gallery (on a fixed page), which I do not have to update all the time by inserting the pictures manually.

Then the easiest way to accomplish it is via [**custom page template**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template).

#### Create the template

1. Copy your `page.php` template file, and name it `template-alpha-gallery.php`
2. At the top, add the following:

   ```
    <?php
    /**
     * Template Name: Alpha Gallery
     */
   ```
3. Keep `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>`, and whatever HTML markup you need to keep. Delete the existing Loop code.
4. Note: the template HTML/loop markup is very Theme-dependent. You'll need to modify these instructions as appropriate for your current Theme.
5. In place of the Loop code, add the shortcode output from below:

   ```
    $alpha_attachments = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => 0,
        'category_name' => 'alpha', // note: use category SLUG
    ) );

    $alpha_id_array = array();

    foreach ( $alpha_attachments->posts as $alpha ) {
        $alpha_id_array[] = $alpha->ID;
    }

    $alpha_ids = implode( ',', $alpha_id_array );

    echo do_shortcode( '[gallery ids="' . $gallery_ids . '"]' );
   ```
6. Create a new Static Page, and assign it the "Alpha Gallery" page template
7. Enjoy your gallery

### Original Answer

The `[gallery]` shortcode doesn't accept a "category" parameter, however, [it does include an `'include'` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode#Options), that accepts a comma-separated list of attachment IDs:

```
[gallery include="1,2,3"]
```

So, you can use `include` to list IDs for all of the attachments that have your specified category.

First, query the correct attachments:

```
$alpha_attachments = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => 0,
    'category_name' => 'alpha', // note: use category SLUG
) );
```

Then, loop through and grab the IDs:

### Edit

You need to *WordPress* loop through the results. Instead of this:

```
$alpha_id_array = array();

foreach ( $alpha_attachments as $alpha ) {
    $alpha_id_array[] = $alpha->ID;
}
```

...do this:

```
$alpha_id_array = array();

if ( $alpha_attachments->have_posts() ) : while ( $alpha_attachments->have_posts() ) : $alpha_attachments->the_post();

    $alpha_id_array[] = get_the_ID();

endwhile; endif;
// Important!
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Then, format the string:

```
$alpha_ids = implode( ',', $alpha_id_array );
```

Then, pass that string to the shortcode. If you're using a custom page template, you can do it like so:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[gallery include="' . $alpha_ids . '"]' );
```

And that should be it.

### Edit

> When I click on the file, it loads the biggest available size. Can you tell me, where is the link creation or the expression for in which size to open. I created custom sizes vor example "gallerysize" or "blogsize", but I do not know, how to use them here in this gallery.

The [`[gallery]` shortcode has a `size` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode#Options). Just add it to your output; for example, for "medium" images:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[gallery size="medium" include="' . $alpha_ids . '"]' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but two questions: 1. As I have 3 categories, do I have to use that code three times in my child functions.php with each category stated? 2. I wanted to use the text field in the Wordpress menu for pages and that does not support PHP code like "echo do_shortcode( '[gallery include="' . $gallery_ids . '"]' );", right? How would I have to address that there then?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do that. You could create three different custom page templates (one for each category), or you could create one custom page template, and then use post custom meta data to pass the category slug to the custom query. In either case, you would need three separate static pages, one for each category. Or, you could create one custom page template, and output all three galleries on the same page, just replicating the code for each gallery.

Comment: I added to my first post, because I still could not reply to it. Is that correct that way then or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, editing your question with updated code that you've tried is correct; thank you for that. But honestly, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with all that code, or how it relates specifically to passing attachments with a particular category to the `[gallery]` shortcode.

Comment: @user1720686 If I understand the problem correctly, you could add a custom shortcode wrapper around the gallery shortcode with the include introduced by @ChipBennett. For example `[modgallery cat="alpha"] `

Comment: Okay, now I am lost totally. Maybe I did something wrong in the first place. So, my goal was this:

Comment: Now totally lost. Goal was to have 3 pages (a, b, c) on which all pictures of a category were shown automatically in a gallery, so that I did not have to link those to that page, whenever I upload a picture. BUT WP does not have categories in the Media. THEREFORE I used the function is_add_categories_to_attachments(). With that I could create categories in the Media menu, I did so (a, b, c). NOW comes the prob. The gallery shortcode does not "see" those categories. THEREFORE I copied it to a child functions.php with that add_filter post_gallery feature, which is correct and there I am stuck :(

Comment: "*THEREFORE I copied it to a child functions.php with that add_filter post_gallery feature, which is correct and there I am stuck*" - that method may or may not be correct, but I think it's *overkill*. My answer uses a *different* method, that avoids the need to filter the gallery shortcode.

Comment: I thought, there is a more elegant way to just alter the gallery_shortcode in the child functions.php. I mean, just add the category feature or connect it to the include feature. But the thing is, I have a bit more than zero PHP knowledge.

Comment: Alright, I will try this tonight. Thank you for the complete edit and solution. I will write later my outcome. :)

Comment: Just posted a reply with the not so much success. :(

Comment: How many attachments have the `people` category? What do you get from a `var_dump( $people_attachments )`?

Comment: I think, it is four pictures with the category set. Where shall I put `<?php var_dump( $people_attachments ); ?>` to?

Comment: Well, I placed it unter your gallery script and I received an awful lot of code. Shall I paste it here or send it in an e-mail or how to show? Or just look on the page: studio-scs.de/people/

Comment: What's important is: did `$people_attachments` return post objects for attachment images with the `people` category?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to answer that question. If you go to that page, you will see exactly, what var_dump dumped.

Comment: That `var_dump()` output an *array of post objects*, where each array index is a different post object. You should be able to look through them, and find the `ID` for each post, and then verify if the IDs correspond to the `ID` for attachment images that have the people category.

Comment: To help save you some time: the post IDs returned in that query are `602`, `603`, `604`, and `605`.

Comment: shouldn't `echo do_shortcode( '[gallery include="' . $gallery_ids . '"]' );` be `echo do_shortcode( '[gallery include="' . $alpha_ids . '"]' );`? Or am I missing where $gallery_ids is declared?

Comment: @StephenS. yes, that was a typo from copying-pasting code from the other part of the answer. Now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Heya, guys, I fixed that to `$people_ids`, but still not working correctly. ONE IMAGE shows up now and the rest does not. var_dump still be shown: studio-scs.de/people ... but to answer your question: 602, 603, 604, 605 are the right IDs for the "people category".

Comment: Okay, so next step of **debugging**: what does `var_dump( $alpha_id_array )` show?

Comment: It says: `array(46) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL [8]=> NULL [9]=> NULL [10]=> NULL [11]=> NULL [12]=> NULL [13]=> NULL [14]=> NULL [15]=> NULL [16]=> NULL [17]=> NULL [18]=> NULL [19]=> NULL [20]=> NULL [21]=> NULL [22]=> NULL [23]=> NULL [24]=> NULL [25]=> NULL [26]=> NULL [27]=> NULL [28]=> NULL [29]=> NULL [30]=> NULL [31]=> NULL [32]=> NULL [33]=> NULL [34]=> NULL [35]=> NULL [36]=> NULL [37]=> NULL [38]=> NULL [39]=> NULL [40]=> NULL [41]=> NULL [42]=> NULL [43]=> NULL [44]=> NULL [45]=> int(605) }`

Comment: That explains a lot. See my edited answer. Instead of a `foreach` loop, you need to loop using the `if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();` style.

Comment: I did that, but then comes this error: `Notice: Undefined property: WP_Query::$have_posts in /srv/www/htdocs/web752/html/wp-content/themes/is-child/peoplegallery.php on line 23
 array(0) { } `

Comment: What is the **actual code** you used. Please **edit your question** with any code that you've tried. Edit: I see that you did that; thanks! Can you include the error message in your question as well?

Comment: Alright, done that. :)

Comment: Hi Chip, I marked your answer as solution. Can you maybe add the missing ()? Thank you again, mate.

Comment: Done! For future reference, anyone can edit answers; you're welcome and encouraged to make such changes when you see them. :)

Comment: Ah, great, I did not know that. Thank you. :)